# Very Difficult Mensa IQ test logic problem (probabilities)

Tags: probability

Two sealed bags, A and B, each contain either a bead or a pearl with equal probability. Someone then puts a pearl into bag B, and then randomly pulls out a pearl. You are then offered your choice of bag to open. Which bag is more likely to contain a pearl, if either?

Comment: If one did not know, what is he pulling back from B, than B seems a better choice (66.6%).

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_p$ and $B_p$ denote the events of the pearl being in $A$ and $B$, respectively.

Let $P$ be the event that 'someone' pulls a pearl from $B$.

$p(P)=p(Ap)\frac{1}{2}+p(B_p)=\frac{3}{4}$

$p(B_p|P)=\frac{1}{2}/\frac{3}{4}=\frac{2}{3}$ and so it is best to choose $B$.